# Can we shorten the direct sum of modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $L,M,N$ be R-modules.

If $L\oplus M \cong L \oplus N $ does this imply $M \cong N$.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a sufficient condition for the isomorphism is that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $L,M,N$ are simple $R$-modules. That is, there are no proper nontrivial sub-modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $L=R\oplus R\oplus\cdots$ (a countable direct sum), $M=R$ and $N=\{0\}$?